# run classpath in external folder war file command Spring java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a war package and wanted to include an external classpath:

in my controller:

I have this following code:

**WebApplication class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource( "classpath:config.properties" )
public class WebApplication{

   public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@Controller
@PropertySource( "classpath:config.properties" )
public class ApplicationController{

     //doing some stuff here

}
```

my folder:

> |-project
>
> ```
> |-src
>    |-main
>      |-java
>        |-com.mypage.temp
>          |-WebApplication.java (main class)
>        |-com.mypage.temp.controller
>          |-ApplicationController (Controller)
>      |-resources
>        |- [some stuff & not putting my properties file here to include externally]
>      |-deploy
>        |-config.properties
> ```

However when I build

> project.war

I put in a remote server (unix):

> |project
>
> ```
>   |-bin
>     |-project.war
>   |-config
>     |-config.properties
> ```
>
> Something/something/something/bin/project.war
>   Something/something/something/config/config.properties

run command:

> java -jar -Dclasspath=/something/something/something/config/config.properties project.war

Error:

```
 Failed to parse configuration class [com.mypage.temp.WebApplication];
 nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
 [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
 2016-12-19 18:13:16.763 ERROR 21662 --- [           main]
 o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to
 parse configuration class [com.mypage.temp.WebApplication]; nested
 exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
 [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), Spring Boot relies on the `spring.config.location` Spring Boot property to specify the location of the environment properties file. 
You may provide it in the command line.

> You can also refer to an explicit location using the
>   spring.config.location environment property (comma-separated list of
>   directory locations, or file paths).
>
> $ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject or
>
> $ java -jar myproject.jar
>   --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties

So, try that :

```
java -jar project.war --spring.config.location=classpath:/something/something/something/config/config.properties
```

Comment: Which is your OS ?

Comment: Unix is my operating system

Comment: Strange. This command works on my machine. Are you sure about the path ? 
Try without classpath : `java -jar project.war --spring.config.location=/something/something/something/config/config.properties`